# Pass data from a Datagrid to a form and vice versa

Tags: datagrid

I have a form called "FrmClientesEdicion" which has a postal code field, I am trying to open the postal code file and return to the first form the information selected in the second form from the datagrid. What happens is that with the code so far the info does not pass to me but rather it opens a new instance of the form "FrmClientesEdicion", help?

1. Open the postal code form "FrmCodigosPosAr" from a button in "FrmClientesEdicion" with this line:

   ```
       Dim f As New FrmCodigosPosAr
   f.ShowDialog()
   ```
2. Search in the form : "FrmCodigosPosAr" select a row and pass data (p.e Code, Name) again to the first one: "FrmClientesEdicion" with this lines:

   ```
   Try
       Dim F As New FrmClienteEdicion
       With F
           .TxtCPOCLI.Text = DG.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString ' The code
           .TxtPOBCLI.Text = DG.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString ' The name city
           .TxtPROCLI.Text = DG.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString ' The state
       End With
   Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("Verifique: " & ex.Message.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
   End Try
   Me.Close()
   ```

This second point doesn't works open a new instance but don`t...
Thanks again
Note: The first form still open, never close it when I open the second one!
The pictures:

[Open form 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uaXn.png)
[Then pass data from FORM2 to the FORM1 AGAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6Y56.png)

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself in case someone needs it

1. In form2 (FrmCodigosPosAr)

   ```
   Public Class FrmCodigosPosAr
   Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
   Public myCaller As FrmClienteEdicion
   ```
2. In form 1, (p.e in a Button to call form2 (FrmCodigosPosAr))

   ```
       Dim myform As FrmCodigosPosAr
   Private Sub BtnBuscaCP_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBuscaCP.Click
   If myform Is Nothing Then
       myform = New FrmCodigosPosAr
       myform.myCaller = Me
   End If
   myform.Show()
   ```

   End Sub
3. And in the form 2 (FrmCodigosPosAr) to pass data to Form1 (FrmClientesEdicion)

   ```
       Try
       If Not myCaller Is Nothing Then
           myCaller.Text = Now.ToLongTimeString
           myCaller.TxtCPOCLI.Text = DG.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
           myCaller.TxtPOBCLI.Text = DG.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
           myCaller.TxtPROCLI.Text = DG.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
       End If
   Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("Verifique: " & ex.Message.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
   End Try
   Me.Close()
   ```